# Elastic search with space

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a Elasticsearch setup which will allow user to search indexes as wild cards.

```
array:3 [
 "index" => "users"
 "type" => "user"
 "body" => array:4 [
 "from" => 0
 "size" => 25
 "sort" => array:1 [
  1 => array:1 [
    "order" => "asc"
  ]
]
"query" => array:1 [
  "bool" => array:1 [
    "should" => array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        0 => array:1 [
          "wildcard" => array:1 [
            "full_name" => "john doe"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
]
]
```

when I pass this array to search function, it is returning an empty array. But there is a document related to "John Doe" and when I run `"full_name" => "john"` search is returning the document.

I feel that the problem is with the space.

```
{
"users": {
"user": {
  "properties": {

    "address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "full_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "industry_name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: May you share index mapping?

Comment: Did you tried the `and` operator?

Comment: @Rob:I have added the index mapping

Comment: @DamForums thank you for your update, but you posted search hit, not index mapping. This is how you can retrive it https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: @Rob:I have put the mapping.i found this link with saying that i should try changing index into not_analyzed.but i cant figure out to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113753/elastic-search-wildcard-search-with-spaces?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming field `full_name` is analyzed by elasticsearch.

The problem in your case is fact that [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#query-dsl-wildcard-query) doesn't analyze search string

> Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (not
>   analyzed).

In you case it means, that elasticsearch stored `john` and `doe` tokens in inverted index, but wildcard query is searching for `john doe` token, and it fails.

What you can do about this:

1. Change index mapping, so `full_name` filed is not analyzed anymore.
   Note: you will have to search for `John Doe` to get match, because
   value wasn't analyzed so `john doe` won't match.
2. You can improve first solution, just by leaving `full_name`
   analyzed, but with custom analyzer(wildcard, lowercase). It will
   allow you to search for text `john doe` or `John Doe`.

   ```
   {
       "settings" : {
           "index" : {
               "analysis" : {
                   "analyzer" : {
                       "lowercase_analyzer" : {
                           "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                           "filter" : [
                               "lowercase"
                           ],
                           "type" : "custom"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       },
       "mappings" : {
           "user" : {
               "properties" : {
                   "id" : {
                       "type" : "integer"
                   },
                   "fullName" : {
                       "analyzer" : "lowercase_analyzer",
                       "type" : "string"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. You can take advantage of [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html), and search against raw
   field.

   ```
   "full_name.raw" => "John Doe"
   ```

Hope it will help you handle your use case.

*UPDATE*

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings) you can find more information how to control index mapping.

Comment: How to change the field into not analyzed?

Comment: @DamForums how do you create index, or you just don't and index is created when the first document was indexed?

Comment: @DamForums sorry I'm not a php guy, but maybe this link will help you handle this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_index_operations.html#_create_an_index_2

Comment: :yes when first document is created then index is created.

Comment: @DamForums so I guess you have to create index explicitly, before you will index first document. Hope my previous link will point you a way.

Comment: fields should be 'analyzer' => 'standard' or 'analyzer' => 'not_analyzed'?because the second parameter throws an error.first is not returning the document

Comment: @DamForums 'index' => 'not_analyzed'

Comment: i used that one and this is the mapping i get. "full_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "omit_norms": true,
          "index_options": "docs"
        }, but still not returning the correct doc

Comment: @DamForums document contains "john doe" or "John Doe". Just to confirm, you are searching for "john doe"?

Comment: Document contain: John Doe and my search parameter is John D or John Doe or john doe.and at the time of searching i convert the value into lowercase.

Comment: indexed token is John Doe and you are searching for john doe, so this is why you don't get match. Maybe try to use my second solution, I guess it's much more flexible, so you will be able to pass "john doe" or "John Doe", and you will get result. I'll update my answer with index mapping.

Comment: @DamForums check my update for second solution, hope it helps this time.

Comment: :will check it and get back to u.thanks for the support through out

Comment: :now i cant create the index.gives me an error.MapperParsingException[Analyzer [lowercase_analyzer] not found for field [address]].may be something to do with my code?

Comment: Looks like you didn't setup lowercase_analyzer in index settings.

Comment: :i have added the index settings.

Comment: Only chance to say something more about your issue in this case is to see how do you create the index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81375/discussion-between-dam-forums-and-rob).

Comment: First methods works fine. Thanks Rob for the support.

Answer (score 0):

I think standard tokenizer will be applied by default.

In that case, it will consider the text john doe as phrase.

So try phrase search

```
"full_name" => "\"john doe\""
```

Comment: This isn't the best way because you're using the Lucene regex engine to do the search, and if some unescaped character is present, this will cause the query throw an exception.

Comment: @fjcero I have made the quick answer for the current case only :)

Comment: great! I have to fight with some of this solutions allowed by ES but when the App grows this things are a little bit messy :P

Comment: @PandiyanCool: this is not working in my problem.can you help me out?

Comment: try using match_phrase

Comment: @PandiyanCool:example?i m new to ES

Comment: @PandiyanCool:can we use match_phrase with wildcard?

Comment: @PandiyanCool:if i use match_phrase with wildcard it doesnt work properly.But if i use match phrase without wildcard it work. But i need the wild card operator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider spaces you could do something like:

```
{
    "match" : {
         "full_name" : {
            "query" : "john doe",
            "operator" : "and",
            "zero_terms_query": "all"
        }
    }
}
```

check this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: :this is not a match.i need a wildcard search.when i try the given code with the search it is not working.