# Elasticsearch match query for Multi Word not Exact word

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes

I am new in elastic search and I'm tired to find data in index document. Like I have 4 documents and there is in 2 fields `fullName, userName` -

```
{
    "_index": "users",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "NwV2GG8BmEFrScbl3IE8",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "fullName": "Max Payne",
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "MaxP"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "users",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "MgV2GG8BmEFrScbl3IE8",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "fullName": "Thomas John",
        "id": 6,
        "userName": "ThomesJ"            
    }
},
{
    "_index": "users",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "MgD2TG1BmEFrrfbs3RT9",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "fullName": "John well",
        "id": 7,
        "userName": "ThomesW"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "users",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "QwR58DTBmEFrScbl8op4",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "fullName": "Max smith",
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "MaxS"
    }
}
```

if search
Case 1
'Ma' then I need 3 document

Case 2
'Max' then I need 2 document

Case 3
'Max s' then I need 1 document  (Max smith)
'Max p' then I need 1 document  (Max Payne)

Case 4
'John' then I need 2 document

I try with this and if full string match then data found otherwise data not found.

```
"bool" : {
    "should": {
        "query_string": {
        "query": '*'+keyword+'*', // "query": keyword+'*',
        "fields": [ "fullName", "userName" ]
        },
    },
}
```

Also, I try with this but not working

```
"term": {
    "fullName": {
    "value": keyword
  }
}
```

I'm using `Elasticsearch 6.3` with NodeJs Client

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch works fundamentally different than you might be expecting here. With the default analyzer you are using, each word in your indexed fields becomes a token which is searchable.

Searching by parts of a token is possible using a **wildcard** query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html). However it is strongly advised to not just blindly use wildcard queries as they don't scale well with a growing index.

If it is absolutely required to search by parts of a token like you described you should check out the **n-gram** token filters (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html).
This would produce tokens like [m,a,x,ma,ax] which would allow you to search for "ma".
Here is an example of the implementation of an ngram-filter:

```
PUT so_example
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram-example": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "ngram"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "users": {
      "properties": {
        "userName": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "ngram-example"
        },
        "fullName": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "ngram-example"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow to perform your searches like:

```
GET so_example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Max Pa",
      "type": "phrase",
      "fields": [
        "fullName"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For your example with "Max P" you need to keep in mind that you are searching for 2 tokens as they are 2 words technically. To search for tokens which need to be in a given order you need **phrase_match** queries (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html). Otherwhise the search term P isn't required to follow Max in the searched field.

Comment: phrase_match look like `var keyword = req.body.search; query = { "match_phrase" : { "fullName" : keyword   } }`,  Right?

Comment: Given that you want to search multiple fields you can combine it with a multi_match query. For example:

"query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Max P",
      "type":       "phrase",
      "fields":     [ "fullName", "userName" ]
    }
  }

Comment: I try your above code but not working (data not found)  `"query":{ "multi_match": { "query": "max P",  "type": "phrase",  "fields": [ "fullName", "userName" ]  } }`

Comment: Be aware that the default analyzer stores fields case sensitive. So your search terms would need to adjust to that. 
My exact example does not match as "Max" and "P" aren't actually tokens in your dataset. "MaxP" would match or "Max Payne". For partial matching like "Max Pa" you would have to look at either n-gram filters or the mentioned wildcard query.

Comment: So, I need to make a change in Index?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example to hopefully illustrate the usage of custom analyzers better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this query and use wildcards according to your different scenarios and you will get the desired results needed

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "fullName": {
        "value": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For instance case 1: "value": "*ma*" 
             case 2: "value": "max" and similarly.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Have a look at this question, it might help u understand better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113753/elastic-search-wildcard-search-with-spaces

Comment: Yes, I already checked before I post my question but it's not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use one new property named '`search_name`' where the username and fullname will get stored. '`copy_to`' would help to achieve this.

Change the index like given below -

```
PUT user_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "edge_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 50
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "trim",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "userName_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",

            "edge_filter"
          ]
        },
        "fullName_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",

            "edge_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "userName": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "userName_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "copy_to": "search_name"
      },
      "fullName": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "fullName_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "copy_to": "search_name"
      },
      "search_name":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "fullName_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now use the search query like below -

```
GET user_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "search_name":{
              "query": "max p",
              "operator" : "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please change the query value according to the requirement given.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tested this in ES7 environment, can you please nest "properties" json object in "_doc" and try. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/copy-to.html